# XML response incorrect Spring REST

Tags: jaxb, spring-rest, jackson-databind, jackson-dataformat-xml

I have a problem when generating XML response of my bean

Controller's method :

```
@GetMapping(value = PING_URL, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Pong> getPingPage() {
    ServicesType services = new ServicesType();
    services.getService().add(this.commonService.getDBSservice());

    final Pong pong = new Pong();
    pong.setVersion(this.commonService.getVersion());
    pong.setServices(services);
    pong.setStatus(this.commonService.getGlobalStatus(pong).name());
    return ResponseEntity.ok(pong);
}
```

Bean :

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
"status",
"version",
"services"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "pong")
public class Pong {

@XmlElement(required = true)
protected String status;
@XmlElement(required = true)
protected String version;
@XmlElement(required = true)
protected ServicesType services;
// GETTER / SETTER
```

Response :

```
<Pong>
<status>OK</status>
<version/>
<services>
    <service>
        <service>
            <status>OK</status>
            <log/>
            <name>BDD</name>
        </service>
    </service>
</services>
</Pong>
```

As you can see, xmlRootElement is "Pong" instead of "pong" but it was ignored.

Have you any idea how to resolve the issue please ?

I'm using Spring (5.3.14) with Jackson (2.13.1).

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem...and nobody seems to know a solution to this..

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it by registering an XML Configuration that tells Jackson to use a Mapper that has the `JaxbAnnotationModule` registered.

```java
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jaxb.JaxbAnnotationModule;

@Configuration
public class MySpringRestServiceXmlConfiguration {

    /**
     * The converter must be declared for @XMLRootElement and @XmlElement annotations to work properly.
     */
    @Bean
    MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter getMappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter() {
        var jaxbAnnotationModule = new JaxbAnnotationModule();
        var mappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter = new MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter();
        mappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter.getObjectMapper().registerModule(jaxbAnnotationModule);
        return mappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to put this in a package that is scanned by your Spring Rest Service Application.